# Click *Show More* to get one more option

Tags: website-design, gui-design, structure

Lately, several companies that I have seen have a *show more* button which simply shows just one option.  An example of this can be found here:

https://getadblock.com/pay/

Would it not be simpler to show all three, and possibly result in ***more*** customers?  If a user quickly scanned the page they'd think:

*Ah, damn, paypal or credit card only... Maybe I can't donate*

Whereas the hidden amazon logo in the example is able to be viewed quickly and easily.

*TL;DR*: Is it too much for a company to put three images shown rather than two?  Does it really overwhelm the user when there is already an addition of a *show more* button.

Comment: Sometimes it is done because they _anticipate more options to come_, and therefore while they are preparing for more options, there is only one more additional option at the time. This would help with training users to know to look for more options, but does become cumbersome if there is only 1 more additional option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could have also been done because the other two options are *preferred*.  For the example you gave, perhaps paying with a credit card or paypal only took 2% off the top of the payment while paying through Amazon might have taken 5% or more.  It would be beneficial to the site owner (but not the user) if the user went through the trouble of making a new account on one of the preferred systems rather than using an existing account on a system that would result in less profit.

Because of such reasons, this style of limiting options is **not recommended** by user experience professionals, though it may be encouraged by upper management.

Comment: When it comes to implementation of a requirement to promote preferred payment options, I actually think this is a pretty good approach from a UX perspective.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not too much to display. I suppose it happened simply because whoever developed this site (most likely Michael himself) was expecting to add more options later or simply didn't know what are the payment options when he was coding the website, so maybe he thought something like: "I'll leave two options for display and hide everything else behind the "More" button", not knowing there is going to be not much of "everything else".

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes this is done for speed / scale.
Only code is loaded for what is considered the primary options.
When you click the more then more stuff is downloaded and more code is loaded. 
I get this is UX and the UX answer is don't want to wait for more. 
The reality is that is takes time to transfer data and load code.